# Why do I get such strange lines of code when I run anaconda prompt?

Tags: keras, anaconda

I have a problem that when I run anaconda prompt, I get this:

[image]

What does this mean, and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Just to make that clear: You open Anaconda Prompt and instead of the empty console window (just `C:\Users\user>`) you get what's displayed in the image? You did not type any of that?

Comment: when I open the Anaconda Prompt I get what is on the image, I do not type. It happened when I install keras update, assuming.

Comment: What are you trying to do on the anaconda prompt? Install a package? If that is the case, then why don't you simply install that package globally using the normal command prompt?

Comment: The code that's running is keras configuration/setup. It seems that this happens in `C:\Users\user\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat`. See if you can find that section in that file. If you don't want keras, uninstall it and remove that section. If you want keras, but not this stuff, remove that section and try if keras still works. If not, this seems to be the preferred way to configure keras on Windows/Anaconda.